Meaning "the waiter grinning in practiced collusion..."

The waiter came by to see if they wanted dessert. “Should we?” Ana asked, breathlessly, the waiter grinning in practiced collusion. Richard couldn’t bear to enact his role, play at naughtiness. “If you want,” he said, lightly, forcing himself to erase any impatience from his voice. But Ana picked up on it anyway.

—Northeast Regional By Emma Cline.
In the paragraph above, why does the waiter grin?
Why he collude?

The waiter grins to collude with Ana in her plot to get dessert. A dictionary will explain the meaning.

Note, the word is "collusion," not "conclusion." Please look up "collusion" in the dictionary, and if you still have questions afterward, use the "edit" button to tell about what you found and what confusion you still have.

@tchrist Your edit broke the question. Unless the OP made a typo, they mistook one word for another, and by "fixing it" you obscured their confusion. Please do not make invasive edits that change the nature of a question.

Background Cultural Knowledge
In the US, there is a common cultural idea that dessert (sweets after dinner) is decadent, luxurious, and maybe a bit naughty. Many Americans eat dessert regularly, but it's something that "healthy" people aren't supposed to want much of, or maybe only on very special occasions. Desserts in restaurants often cost a larger amount per item than a non-dessert item of the same size, and they are an optional expense.
Waiters in the US work for tips - which is typically a percentage of the final bill, so they are incentivized to encourage customers to order more expensive items.
Colluding
In this passage, the reader is meant to visualize that this waiter commonly asks customers if they want dessert and hears them say something like "oh, I shouldn't." or maybe "yes, since it's a special occasion." Much of this is a social script - they want dessert, but feel it would be rude or socially incorrect to admit so.
The waiter wants customers to order dessert because it raises his tipped amount, so he plays along with the customer's fake hesitance by trying to convince them.
To collude is to scheme or plan subtly together. In this instance, the word refers to the fact that the customer and the waiter typically want the same thing - for the waiter to bring dessert. But that the customer feels pressure to subtly justify it to everyone there.
Second Sentence
The second sentence simply says that Richard is tired of this social game, or distracted, or wants to leave. So he doesn't play along into the conversation. He offers neither an objection to dessert nor an excuse for Ana to get it.

It's also a cultural thing that when ordering dessert, people often ask for two spoons, as it were. Sharing a dessert is common.

thanks alot, I looked up in dictionary, " naughtiness" has many synonyms, what is the correct synonym of it in this context?
